# Hover one element of linked elements

Tags: html, css

I have a circle and a text string grouped together in a page. I am trying to implement 3 possible situations:

. situation 1: when no elements are hover, only the circle should appear,

. situation 2: when the circle is hover, both the circle and the linked text should appear,

. situation 3: when the text is hover, only the circle should appear.

I can only implement the first 2 situations.

My attempt below:

```css
.shape_text:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  opacity: 0;
}

.text:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="250">
  <g class="shape_text">
      <circle cx="30" cy="45" r="25" />
      <text class="text" x=0 y=100>That's a circle</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but your text will always have an opacity 0 unless you hover the circle? So how am I supposed to know where the text is to hover over it and hide the circle?

Comment: The circle should always be visible in all situations. The user could (not intentionally) hover the text when navigating the page. But you are right, you know where is the text only after hovering the circle once.

Comment: Exactly, at a UX level this is just not right. The user will never have a clue to hover over the text. What are you trying to do specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description seems a bit strange: What you wrote means that the circle should always be visible (1,2,3) and the text should only appear when the circle is hovered (2), which is quite easy:

```css
text {
  opacity: 0;
}

circle:hover + text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="250">
  <g class="shape_text">
      <circle cx="30" cy="45" r="25" />
      <text class="text" x=0 y=100>That's a circle</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the behaviour I was after. Would it be possible to do the same by defining a class. In the case for instance where there would be a first shape linked to "This is shape 1" text string, and a second shape linked to "Here is shape 2" text string. In a way that both text strings should appear at the same location in the page when their respective shape is hover.

Comment: certainly you should use classes or IDs, i definitely would do it that way. The identical location for the two texts could be done by using `position: absolute` (or `fixed`, depending on the situation) with identical position settings for the two texts (should be within the same relative-positioned parent)